# What is the best way to check if a field on a registration form is unique?

Tags: angular

I'm building a project where I also build the server side used Spring and the client side using angular.

On the client side there is a registration form, in which the user is asked to fill out an email and password.

Because the email is essential for connecting to the system, it must be unique.
Therefore, on the server side I have defined that when a client tries to insert an email that already exists he will get an exception.

Since I do not want the client to send requests to return an error I created a server-side function to check if there is already a client with the email that the user has entered that returns true or false.
And I determined that the function will be activated once the user has finished entering a value in the email input box using the blur event.
The problem is that the function that is enabled is asynchronous and allows the user to send the form before the answer is returned.

What to do ? How is it possible to check whether a unique field already exists?
Reminds me that I work with angular 7 and not using reactive form but a standard form

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, @ChayMizrahi! I can tell you that if you don't include what you have tried, you probably won't find much help on SO. People are more than happy to help someone figure something out, but are much less apt to just do someone else's work for them.

Comment: The statistical chance that user's will enter duplicate emails is very small. Even on a large website. So just leave it as a POST rejection when the form is submitted. Have the server yield a response back that says the email already exists, and take it from there. Performing early async validation to solve such a rare problem is just over engineering to me.

Comment: Well, you could disable the form submit button until you know that the email is not used already, for example. But whatever you do, there is always a chance that someone else registers with the same email just after you've checked for uniqueness, and before the form submission. But given that the user is supposed to have a unique email anyway, I agree with Reactgular. You will confirm the registration by actually verifying that the user indeed owns that email address, right (i.e. y sending a confirmation email and waiting for a confirmation)?

Comment: FYI if you use a reactive form, the form won't register as valid until async validation completes, and it's worthwhile to learn how to use reactive forms effectively if you want to develop in angular in any event.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.
The user will insert any object which is one of its fields must be unique.
I used an example email just to make it easy to understand me.
Apparently I should have been more detailed and give a more specific example.
In any case, it seems that I have no choice but to learn a bit about the reactive form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in an angular environment... it's probably easiest to just use reactive forms.

if you had a component template like:

```
<div [formGroup]="registrationForm'>
  <input type="email" formControlName="email">
  <input type="password" formControlName="password">
  <button type="submit" (click)="register()">Register</button>
</div>
```

and a controller like

```
export class RegistrationComponent {
  registrationForm: FormGroup;

  private uniqueEmail() {
    return (ctrl: AbstractControl) => { // this is how you define a validator function
      let email = ctrl.value;
      return (value) // async validators return an Observable or Promise
        ? this.checkUniqueEmail(email).pipe(
            map(isUnique => (isUnique) ? null : {emailNotUnique: true})
          ) // validators return null if they're valid, otherwise some object
        : of(null); // don't bother checking if no value
    }
  }

  private checkUniqueEmail(email) {
    // whatever your actual uniqueness checker is here, 
    // must return Observable<boolean> in this example
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append("email", email);
    return this.http.get<boolean>('https://example.com/check-unique-email', {search: params});
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email], // sync validators, these are both angular built in's
        asyncValidators: [this.uniqueEmail()], // this is how you use a validator
        updateOn: 'blur' // run validation on blur
      }],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]] // short hand declare validators
    });
  }

  register() {
    if (this.registrationForm.valid) {
      // async validation done and form valid, do the save
    } else {
      // form is not valid or async validation in flight
    }
  }
}
```

you've now declared `uniqueEmail` as an async validator for the email form control in your registration form.  The form itself will not register as valid until async validation completes. and validation won't run until the control is blurred.